# Postman returning same result even when URL changes

Tags: postman

I'm new to postman. I've watched some tutorials and read some of the docs but it's a bit confusing to me.

I'm trying to test some api endpoints I set up on a controller.
When I enter in LocalHost:3002 I'm getting a response.
When I enter in LocalHost3002:/Passengers Same response
When I enter in LocalHost3002:/Passengers/GeraldLee  Same response

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely a problem with your backend rather than postman itself. Without further information is hard for me to say, but it seems you're processing all requests equally.

Also, the correct format for the request is as follows:

```
GET localhost:3002/passengers/GerardLee
```

which follows the format:

```
http_verb hostname:port/specific_endpoint
```

Try to check if the format you're using in postman is correct, maybe that helps too.